# Exchange 2013 Virtual Directory

Tags: exchange-2013

Someone have deleted Default Website from IIS.

How can i re-create the Exchange virtual directory for Default Website and Exchange Back End Website?

I found a command:

```
New-OwaVirtualDirectory -InternalUrl 'https://mail.domain.local/owa' -WebSiteName 'Default Web Site'
```

But i need to re-create everything like Exchange installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think you'd do best to reinstall/repair the Exchange installation if all of your websites are missing.

If you're only missing some of the virtualDirectorys you could rebuild them buy running the following command in Exhcange Management Shell.

New-ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory -WebSiteName "Default Web Site" -ExternalURL "https://mail.domain.local/Microsoft-
 Server-ActiveSync"

The same goes for the other virtualdirectorys like, OWA, ECP

New-OWAVirtualDirectory

New-ECPVirtualDirectory